# How do you specify alternative script interpreters (shebangs)?

Tags: ruby, env

In an executable file, you specify the environment using a shebang:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

# ruby code here
```

But what if you want to specify multiple possible environments?  For example, if you have multiple versions of Ruby installed, you may want to do something like

```
#!/path/to/better/ruby/version
#!/path/to/alternative/ruby/version

# ruby code here
```

How can you specify multiple possible environments for a single executable file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't.

The idea behind using `#!/usr/bin/env ruby` instead of simply `#!/usr/bin/ruby` is to use whatever ruby binary is first in the user's path. Then your script doesn't depend on ruby being in the same place on every system; after all, a 'normal' ruby location might be `/usr/bin/ruby`, `/usr/local/bin/ruby`, `/opt/ruby-1.8.7/bin/ruby`, etc...

If you DID want to hardcode some values or do some searching logic, you could always make a wrapper shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

for ruby in /usr/bin/ruby /usr/local/bin/ruby
do
    if [ -x "$ruby" ]
    then
        "$ruby" myscript.rb
        break
    fi
done
```

And if you're sufficiently motivated, you could even [embed a ruby (or other) script](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=46168) inside the shell script.

Comment: That makes sense.  I plan to run this script on multiple machines, each of which has a different path to Ruby 1.9, and they don't all use Ruby 1.9 as the default interpreter.  I'll try using the wrapper script. Thanks!

Comment: Don't forget to `$@` when calling the final script to forward possible args: `"$ruby" myscript.rb $@`

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to contradict mrb and say that you can do alternates, *without* changing the "#!" line.

Suppose you have a ruby script with `#!/usr/bin/env ruby` as the first line.

You want `/path/to/better/ruby/version/whatever` to run the script, you set the PATH environment variable to have `/path/to/better/ruby/version` first:

```
PATH=/path/to/better/ruby/version:$PATH  whatever_script_name_is
```

You want `/usr/local/bin/ruby` to run the script?  Set PATH appropriately:

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH  whatever_script_name_is
```

Note that fiddling with PATH can cause other problems in the case that the ruby executable you want to run the script resides in the same directory with *other* alternate programs. For example, if `/usr/local/bin` had BSD `cat`, `grep`, `sed` in it as well as `ruby`, then when you set `PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH` you will get the BSD executables instead of Linux executables.  That could case a problem.